# Xamarin.Forms doesn't find migrations of EntityFramework.Core

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core, migration

I Am wondering what i am doing wrong because EnsureCreated() works as i want but Migrate() doesn't work because no migrations are ever found.

Here is some code:

```
public SqliteContext(string FileName)
{
   this.FileName = FileName;
   Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

Works

But when i do the same but with:

```
public SqliteContext(string FileName)
{
   this.FileName = FileName;
   Database.Migrate();
}
```

It doesn't. So i checked and it seems no migrations are ever found. But i have my migrations in the same project as my SqliteContext/dbContext. (In map Migrations) So i assume i don't have to specify a migration assembly but i did that as well but it still didn't work.

For some extra information:

My migrations are generated by Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.

I am using:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 3.1.12
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 3.1.12
Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012
Xamarin.Essentials 1.6.1
```

```
FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "narco.db"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems i found the solution.

```
public class DbMigrationContext : SqliteContext
    {
        public DbContext() : base(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "narco.db"))
        {
            
        }
    }
```

I added this class to my Core project so if there were any changes in my context i use in my project they auto reflect in the context i use to create my migrations.

```
    [DbContext(typeof(DbMigrationContext))]
```

Is put on top of my migration so its not found. So when i changed it to

```
    [DbContext(typeof(SqliteContext))]
```

It now works as expected. So i guess from now on i will just disconnect the reference to my project with my SqliteContext and just copy it over to avoid issues like this.

Hopefully whoever has this issue will find this useful.